# What resources can be nested in azure terraform?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

What resources can be nested within another resource in Azure terraform?

Can we nest the creation of resource: network_interface / IP_configuration within a VM deployment (virtual_machine) even though virtual_machine contains the parameter: network_interface_ids ?  Can I assume it is best to place network_interface / IP configurations outside this VM nest?

More importantly, how do we know what resources can be nested and which resources cannot be nested?

Answer (score 1):

Usually resources in Terraform are not nested. The documentation typically covers if there is the potential to do inlining of resources, which is rare.

Typically, you create all your resources at the same level, then reference the NIC ids or IP configurations inside of your Virtual Machine. The other doesn't matter either in which you define these in your Terraform file. Terraform will build out a depedency graph for you to determine the order that resources need created.

You can see this in the example from the docs:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-nic"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.internal.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-vm"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.main.id}"]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  # Adding Availability zones
  zones = [1]
}
```

Here is the [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html) to the example.

Comment: After examining you link  -  https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html
I noticed that the following are all nested within azurerm_virtual_machine: storage_image_references, stroage_os_disk, os_profile, os_profile_lunix_config, and tags.
Can these items function outside azurerm_virtual_machine nesting?   Is it possible to add dependencies to the nested items to the virtual machine?
One other question?,...  If I wanted to deploy a vm into a specific availability zone how would I do this?,... can you please give me an example.    
Thank You.

Comment: @kimdav111 No there isn't way to currently do that from what I am aware. If those existed separately they would be listed as resources in the documentation. Since they are not resoruces then I don't think they can have dependency blocks.  You have assign zones by adding the zones property for one you created.